# IsMouseOver Is Not Triggered When Hovering Over The Padding Or The Margin Of A Control Template Children

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm

The problem is that the IsMouseOver trigger is not triggered when hovering over the padding or the margin of the inner control template children.

I have this control template. And I want the IsMouseOver trigger to be triggered where ever I hover over this control template. It only works when I hover over the text or over the border.

```xml
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="IBeam"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Border Margin="0 35 0 0" 
                                Padding="0 0 0 12" 
                                BorderThickness="0 0 0 3" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
                                              FontSize="22" 
                                              Foreground="{StaticResource GreyColor}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Email" 
                                           FontSize="22" 
                                           Foreground="{StaticResource GreyColor}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: When no background color is specified, that is, it is null, clicks go through it.
Set the anchor to the background `<Border ... Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">`.
And in the setter TextBox set the color for Background.
If you need transparent, then Transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the Margin from the Border to the Grid, and set a Background on the Border:

```
<Border Padding="0 0 0 12" BorderThickness="0 0 0 3"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">

    <Grid Margin="0 35 0 0">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Email" FontSize="22"
                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```